# shortcode for jquery function

Tags: jquery, shortcode

```
$('#r2').click(function() {
            $('.r2_s').show();
            $('.r1_s').hide();
            $('.r3_s').hide();
            $('.r4_s').hide();
            $('#r2').addClass("active");
            $('#r1').removeClass("active");
            $('#r3').removeClass("active");
            $('#r4').removeClass("active");
        });
```

Now i would like to write this a little bit shorter. i've tried this one:

```
$('#r2').click(function() {
            $('.r2_s').show();
            $('.r1_s').$('.r3_s').$('.r4_s').hide();
            $('#r2').addClass("active");
            $('#r1').$('#r3').$('#r4').removeClass("active");
        });
```

unfortunately it doesn't work. how can i shorten that?

thanks 
thomas

Comment: $('.r2_s').show();$('r1_s, .r3_s, .r4_s').hide();$('#r2').addClass("active"); $('#r1, #r3, #r4').removeClass("active");

Comment: can share the relevant html - looks like you have more click handlers

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
$('#r1, #r2, #r3, #r4').click(function() {
    $('.r1_s, .r2_s, .r3_s, .r4_s').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).attr('id') + '_s').show();

    $('#r1, #r2, #r3, #r4').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use commas

```
$('.r1_s, .r3_s, .r4_s').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use selectors rather than chaining.

```
$('#r2').click(function() {
    $('.r2_s').show();
    $('.r1_s, .r3_s, .r4_s').hide();
    $('#r2').addClass("active");
    $('#r1, #r3, #r4').removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#r2').click(function() {
        $('.r2_s').show();
        $('.r1_s,.r3_s,.r4_s').hide();            
        $('#r2').addClass("active");
        $('#r1,#r3,#r4').removeClass("active");
    });
```